# How do I remove duplicate programs in Classic menu indicator? [Ubuntu 14.04]

Tags: 14.04, gnome, uninstall, indicator, menu

I have installed Cisco Packet Tracer Student 6.2 in Ubuntu 14.04. It works, but it has been shown for three times in the Classic MenuIndicator.
You can check my situation by clicking the link to see the picture. The Packet Tracer link with the green dot works. The other two, with the red dots, do not work! How can I remove those not working links?

http://prntscr.com/7geyyx

Comment: Did you tried reboot?If yes then go to `/usr/share/applications` and find the program.If it's multiplied remove the red ones from that location(just in case you need them if something goes wrong).

Comment: Before this post I had already three NOT working links. One link, named Cisco Packet Tracer 6.2, I have already removed in that way. If I have finished a reboot, it's still there.

Comment: You might want to use `alacarte`.It helps you edit the classic menu indicator.See if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a menu editor like Alacarte (package `alacarte`, the menu entry is named "Main Menu") to modify the menu.

For every menu item there's a `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` or `$HOME/.local/share/applications/`. You can try to find the files there and remove them.

Alacarte will not remove the files if you remove an menu item, but will add a line

```
Hidden=true
```

that causes the item not to be displayed.

Comment: I have installed Main Menu. I can uncheck Cisco Packet Tracer, but then is my working link gone! the other two or still in the list and I can't find it in the program. Even the .desktop files aren't in /usr/share/applications.

Comment: Are there .desktop file in `$HOME/.local/share/applications/`?  In any case please file a bug report and attache every .desktop file related to Cisco Packet Tracer that you can find.

Comment: Thank you! My problem is solved! I have used the terminal to go into that directory because you can't come there through GUI? But that afterwards, I have found two .desktop files which I've moved to my user directory because I was not sure. But these two files were the problem! I've removed them and only the working icon is in the ClassicMenu Indicator. Click the link to see the files I've removed.

Comment: http://1drv.ms/1BkGOkl